# Opensuse Leap 42.1: xsp & fast-mono-server problems

Tags: asp.net, fastcgi, opensuse, mono

I have recently upgraded my opensuse machine from 12.2 to Leap 42.1 (x86_64). It's mostly going well. However, I installed mono & xsp via yast (KDE) and I have found that both xsp & fastcgi-mono-server4 are unwell.

If I ask these modules (mono, xsp & fastcgi-mono-server4) for their version numbers, this is what I get back:-

```
 #mono -V
    Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.4 (Stable 4.0.4.1/5ab4c0d Sun Oct 25 12:51:49 UTC 2015)
    Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen

    #xsp -V
Exception caught during reading the configuration file:
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager:get_AppSettings (): IL_0000: ret       


  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
XSP server is a sample server that hosts the ASP.NET runtime in a
minimalistic HTTP server

    #fastcgi-mono-server --version
    Unhandled Exception:
    System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Xml.XmlDocument:GetElementsByTagName (string): IL_0000: ret       


      at Mono.WebServer.ConfigurationManager.ImportSettings (System.Xml.XmlDocument doc, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection, Boolean allowDuplicates, Boolean insertEmptyValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.WebServer.ConfigurationManager..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly asm, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Xml.XmlDocument:GetElementsByTagName (string): IL_0000: ret       


      at Mono.WebServer.ConfigurationManager.ImportSettings (System.Xml.XmlDocument doc, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection, Boolean allowDuplicates, Boolean insertEmptyValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.WebServer.ConfigurationManager..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly asm, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I notice that the mono Architecture is amd64, where I'm expecting x86_64.

And of course both xsp & fastcgi-mono-server4 complain about unhandled exceptions.

Does anyone know want I can do to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I have resovled this issue.

I installed xsp via yast & zypper several times without improvment. Finally, I tried installing directly from

https://software.opensuse.org/package/xsp

This has made the crital difference for me - fastcgi-mono-server4 no longer complains about unhandled exceptions. However, xsp still does. But given that I don't really want xsp, it doesn't worry me.

My nginx <> fast-mono-server4 <> asp.net web server is WORKING!

Now to do something clever with it...